# How to multiply functions

Tags: python

For instance, I have defined two functions:

```
def f1(x, y):
   x + y
def f2(x, y):
   x**y
```

How to get a function such as:

```
f = f1 * f2
```

I know in probfit I can use `probfit.AddPdf` to add two functions. Is there a similar way to multiply two functions?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new function that returns the result of those two functions multiplied:

```
def f1(x, y):
    return x + y

def f2(x, y):
    return x**y

def f(x, y):
    return f1(x, y) * f2(x, y)
```

Or if you are looking to multiply 2 functions without knowing their args, you could do something like this:

```
def f(*args):
    return f1(*args) * f2(*args)
```

Which will act in exactly the same way:

```
print(f(2, 3)) # => 40
```

And you can use a lambda if you want it to be shorter:

```
f = lambda x, y : f1(x, y) * f2(x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you for the replying. The problem is there are many parameters in my function and the function multiplied in my case is a sum of several individual functions. Therefore, I can't use this simple method in my program. Do you know any package could multiply two function and merge the parameters of the two functions according to their name?

Comment: There isn't a more succinct way to multiply / sum them implicitly, like you're describing. But if you describe what these functions do, and why you have so many of them, I might be able to come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just define it:

```
def f(x, y):
    return f1(x, y) * f2(x, y)
```

Make sure you add a `return` statement to `f1` and `f2` so that they don't just throw away their results.

Comment: Thank you for the replying. The problem is there are many parameters in my function and the function multiplied in my case is a sum of several individual functions. Therefore, I can't use this simple method in my program. Do you know any package could multiply two function and merge the parameters of the two functions according to their name?